# Does the UserCreationForm from the django.contrib.auth.forms in django not work anymore?

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views

I was trying to register a new user through the frontend with the help of django but i saw quite a few tutorials use UserCreationForm but for my case it does't seem to work.

**views.py**

```
def registerUser(request) :
    form = RegisterForm()
    context = {'form':form}

    if request.method == 'POST' :
        form = RegisterForm(request.POST) 
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            messages.success(request, 'User Created succesfully')
            print('user Created')
            return redirect('users:login')
        else :
            print('Not valid')

return render(request, 'register.html', context)
```

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class RegisterForm(UserCreationForm):
   email = forms.EmailField()

   class Meta:
       model = User
       fields = ["username", "email", "password1", "password2"]
```

My `is_valid()` function is giving me that the `request.POST` isn't valid.

Answer (score 0):

Look at Django's [UserCreationForm](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/forms.py#L82) source code.

```py
# default
class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = ("username",)
    field_classes = {'username': UsernameField}
```

By implementing your own fields, you are potentially destroying Django's default form. All I can see, the error lies as you did not set `field_classes` for username. Try changing that.

Answer (score 0):

In Your `forms.py` try this,

```py
class UserCreateForm(UserCreationForm):
    fields = ('username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2', 'first_name', 'last_name')
    model = YOUR_MODEL_THAT_YOU_HAVE_CREATED()

    class Meta:
       # Some Custom Options...
```